# line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `|'

Tags: linux, shell

I was just trying to do a pacman map. But this error came.

**My Code:**

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 to understand why posting images for questions is usually not helpful. Glad you got a solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: nevermind my question below. The problem is that you have an extra `"` in your first line. A text editor with syntax highlight would have made that very clear. But the `;;` and the `done` are both probably wrong nevertheless.

<strike>Are you certain it's not `unexpected token ;;`?</strike> The sequence `;;` is wrong in the context you are using it.

The `echo`s seem fine, but that `done` at the end looks wrong, unless you are in a `for`/`while` loop that you didn't include in your question. Post your whole code instead of a screenshot of it.

Comment: Thank you sir, that solved my problem. Do you know how can i make the dots yellow ?

Comment: The the terminal can use a different set of colors, but you probably want `\033[93m` or `\033[43m`. Try numbers from 90-97 and 40-47. Also check Wikipedia for [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for more information.